Unable to uninstall failing USB driver
I found an old Nokia phone and wanted to check it before I sent it for recycling. When I tried to install the latest USB drivers for the phone the installation failed and now I get a regular pop up saying the last device I connected failed on my Windows 10 machine. I have tried selecting uninstall in the Device Manager but that does not work. Any tips on how to fix this annoying issue which make my machine pop up a message every 5 seconds?

When uninstalling the device via Device Manager, is the box being ticked to delete install files and is the machine being rebooted afterwards?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have tried to delete the driver when it pops up in Device Manager by right clicking the line and selecting uninstall device in the list. After doing that no other choices are offered.

Dear mister ROCHE, you are mistaken, unistalling device in the device manager doesn't really unistall then as the device manager will always look for a "compatible driver", your issue isn't unistalling the device but rather looking for the right driver

@Maslie That makes sense. How can I stop it looking for that device driver? The phone is no longer connected and It is not essential that it could be. I have tried installing the driver again and activating the verify tool which caused a blue screen on startup but did not produce an error that I could use to identify a solution.

You can look through your Device Manager for devices with error icons on them, or you can show disconnected devices and try to find your Nokia device, and once you find either of these ,delete them.

wait a driver causes a blue screen on startup? Are you sure this is related?

@Maslie I believe it is expected. The verify tool will cause a crash when an invalid driver loads. It is supposed to show the place the crash happened, but it didn't tell me anything useful.
[link] https://imgur.com/a/Qg4X8MV [/link]

You have used WinDBG to verify what driver caused that BSOD?
